# EF Core 3.1 Migrations Not Seeing Changes

Tags: entity-framework-core

I've created a code-fist model for entity framework core.  I did an add-migration and noticed somethings weren't correct.  So, I removed the migration, made my changes and tried again.  After several cycles of add/remove/add/remove... I was seeing things not change.

Here the model I'm having problems with:

```
namespace CompetenciesDataModel {
/// <summary>
/// This entity represents the different Competencies that an employee may have, plus a comptency may have
/// have skills that are shared across competencies.
/// This entity is a look up table that can only be modifed by an administrator.
/// </summary>
public class Competency {
    /// <summary>
    /// The primary key for the competencies
    /// </summary>
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]
    public Guid             CompetencyId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the competency
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string           CompetencyName  { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of skills that are part of this competency
    /// </summary>
    public List< CompetencySkillAssoc > CompetenciesAndSkills { get; set; }
}
```

Notice there are three items. When I do the add-migration, the scaffolding code shows three items, except the third one is called Competencies and not CompetenciesAndSkills. It is of type Guid and then is setup as an index on a column that I didn't create. When I look at the other indexes being created they are being done on the primary key. I've even stated that the CompetencyId is a Key and I still get the same result.

The CompetenciesAndSkills is an association table for a many-to-many relationship with a different table.

There isn't any tables within the DB since it doesn't exist, is there anywhere there's a cache that I'm missing to clear? Or, am I just not understanding something else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Competency entity is used as a lookup table.  Therefore, when I attempted to have the Competency entity as part of a different entity (call it EntityX), the migration created a Foriegn Key within the Competency entity.  After realizing that this was a look up and wasn't going to change much (unless some product adminstrator edited).
EntityX had a one-to-many relationship with Competency.  Therefore, I created a new entity that contained a key to EntityX and the Competency entity.  When I did the migration I didn't have an extra column being made that contained the foriegn key back to EntityX.